# Вывод нескольких строк в QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlineedit, qtextedit

Возник вопрос касаемо вывода текста в объект `QTextEdit`. Чтобы выводить информацию я использую `setText`, но как решить проблему если я хочу вывести более 100 строчек в поле `textEdit`?

Писать каждую строчку вывода крайне не разумно, поэтому хотелось бы узнать как это реализовать корректно.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def clicked(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.textEdit.setText(f"{text}") # Здесь нужно вывести 20-30 строк текста, введенным пользователем.
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(347, 243)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 131, 61))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 121, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 20, 93, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 321, 181))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите текст:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно понял вашу задумку, но обратите внимание на:

- НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
  Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
- Познакомьтесь с сигналом [**QLineEdit::editingFinished()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished).
- Познакомьтесь со свойством [**placeholderText : QString**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop)
- Бумаю что вам надо использовать [**QTextEdit::append(const QString &text)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append)

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(347, 243)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 131, 61))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 121, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 20, 93, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 321, 181))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите текст:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print!"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите текст...')
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        
        # Здесь нужно вывести 20-30 строк текста, введенным пользователем.
#        self.textEdit.setText(f"{text}") 
        self.textEdit.append(f"{text}") 
        
        self.lineEdit.clear() 
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]